# Calculate Shortest Path given only starting node in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, shortest-path, path-finding

Consider below matrix and calculate shortest path to reach nearest index having value 2.

Start node: (1,2)

Mat = [

```
    2,0,1,0,0,1
    1,0,1,1,0,0
    2,1,0,0,1,2
    1,0,1,0,0,1
    0,0,2,1,1,2
    0,0,1,1,2,1
```

]

Please give me any clue how we can find the shortest path route in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a basic `BFS` to search for the nearest `2` from a particular starting index.